# For a divergent positive series$\sum a_n$, what can we say about the series $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+ n a_n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

If $a_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and if $\sum a_n$ diverges, what can we say about the convergence or divergence of the series $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+n a_n}$?

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists, then 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{1+n a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{a_n} + n} = 0.$$ 
But this doesn't lead to an answer to my question, I'm afraid.

Comment: It can still diverge. For example, take $a_n=1/n$

Comment: @GLay yes, you're right, but does this new series always diverge?

Comment: Yes, compare it with $1/n$. The limit is $1$

Comment: $\frac{a_n}{1+n a_n} = \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+n a_n}$ so it depends if $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+n a_n}$ converges

Comment: For an example where $\sum a_n$ diverges and $\sum b_n$ converges with $b_n=\frac{a_n}{1+na_n}$, consider $a_{n^2}=\frac1n$ for every $n$ and $a_n=\frac1{n^2}$ for every $n$ which is not a square, then $b_{n^2}=\frac1{n(n+1)}$ for every $n$ and $b_n=\frac1{n(n+1)}$ for every $n$ which is not a square hence $\sum a_n$ diverges and $\sum b_n$ converges.

Comment: @Did is there any particular criterion for divergent positive-term series $\sum a_n$ whose corresponding $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ converge or diverge, respectively? I mean can we give a criterion for a divergent positive term series $\sum a_n$ so that its $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ series diverges? converges?

Comment: For every divergent series $\sum a_n$ with nonnegative terms, the series $\sum\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$ diverges as well. For every divergent series $\sum a_n$ with nonnegative terms, if $a_n\leqslant\frac{c}n$ for some positive $c$, for every $n$ large enough, then the series $\sum\frac{a_n}{1+na_n}$ diverges as well. Of course, this is a partial criterion.

Comment: @Did I'm sorry but actually I meant to ask the following: Is (are) there any necessary and/or sufficient (set of) condition(s) for a divergent positive-term series $\sum a_n$ to satisfy so that the series $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}$ converges? or diverges?  I know that if $a_n > 0$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges, then so deos $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$.